# Is nullptr in C++ the same as null in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, null, nullptr

Is nullptr in C++ the same as null in C#?

Seems like no one asked this question on Google or Stackflow.

Comment: At a distance, yes. Depends on how far you're willing to go in your definition of them being the same.

Comment: I think deep internally it is `0` that old `NULL` but not sure.

Comment: @pranitkothari, `NULL` is essentially 0. `nullptr` is completely different.

Comment: @chris Yes, but I am talk about internals. Still, I am not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general yes, both assign the null value to pointer like types

- C#: class, interface, delegate or pointer types
- C++: pointer types or pointer-to-member type

It doesn't convert to numeric values in either language.  One difference though is that in C++ `nullptr` can convert to `bool`.  This is not true in C#

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In C++, `nullptr` is the equivalent of `null` in Java, C#, and a variety of other languages. Prior to C++11, it was standard to use `NULL` (which was a macro defined as 0); however, `nullptr` actually ensures that it can be used only in the context of pointers (whereas `NULL`, by virtue of having been defined as 0, can also be used as the return value for a function that returns an `int` instead of a pointer, which is counterintuitive), though both `nullptr` and `NULL` are implicitly convertible to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the same. It is the invalid pointer.