# Correct null pointer checking and declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr

I have constructor for my base class named BaseClass

```
BaseClass::BaseClass(BaseClass* parent)
{
    if (parent != 0)
    {
        parent->children.push_back(this);
    }
    this->parent = parent;
    ready = 1;
}
```

This method checks if pointer to parent object is 0 or null and sets it as parent of current object and after it sets ready state of current object to 1.

I read articles where author used `nullptr` keyword in pointer declaration. C++ also allows me to use 0 to declare null pointer but should I use `nullptr` keyword instead of 0 in my constructor for example if I pass null pointer to it as 0?

Comment: Maybe this will help clarify the use of nullptr. [Is nullptr in C++ the same as null in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550916/is-nullptr-in-c-the-same-as-null-in-c)

Comment: Well it seems ```nullptr``` is more correct because sometimes compiler can not understand what 0 is, is this integer or null pointer?.